# Streaming video data to and from uberspace via nodejs and jsmpeg

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-wstunnel

I am trying to stream video data to and from uberspace via nodejs and jsmpeg.

My problem is that I'm getting a 404 when trying to access the url:

`The requested URL /receive was not found on this server.`

The url I am accessing is like this:
`https://stream.mydomain.com/receive`

and this is my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^send/(.*) http://localhost:61624/$1
RewriteRule ^receive/(.*) ws://localhost:61625/$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here.

1) This rule `RewriteRule ^receive/(.*) ws://localhost:61625/$1` matches on `/receive/xxx` with a trailing slash after `receive` (`xxx` part as optional). So you need to access at least `/receive/` in your case. Is it what you expect ? If not, simply adapt your rules.

2) You need to use `mod_proxy` for both rules (use of the `P` flag)

```
RewriteRule ^send/(.*)$ http://localhost:61624/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^receive/(.*)$ ws://localhost:61625/$1 [P]
```

Note, though, that this method is not the fastest. If possible, use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` inside your apache config instead of an htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that.

Comment: I get a 500 now, but that seems to be another problem. Anyway, your answer helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: Turns out that uberspace doesn't support websockets yet.